# Psql escape double qoutes

Tags: postgresql, powershell, psql

I wrote a shell script using psql. I want to export some schema (e.g. "9999") to csv. but I'm not able to overcome this double quotes synatx error:

```
psql -d "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres" -c "\copy "9999".scenario TO 'scenario.csv' (DELIMITER ',', ENCODING 'UTF8', FORMAT CSV, HEADER)"
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrjKO.png)

any help will be appreciated

Comment: `"\\\copy \"9999\"..."`…?

Comment: @deceze - no, it didn't work

Comment: "Didn't work" *how*? What error or other problem are you encountering exactly?

Comment: @deceze - here is a screenshot

Comment: 1) Mention that you're using Powershell. 2) Post the error messages here as text, not as link to an image.

Comment: @deceze, found a solution. please upvote me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution!

```
echo "\copy ""9999"".scenario TO 'scenario.csv' (DELIMITER ',', ENCODING 'UTF8', FORMAT CSV, HEADER)"  | psql -d "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres"
```